# Email validation using javascript in Scala Play Framework?

Tags: javascript, validation

I am getting an error "Expected ending '}'" in browser for using @ symbol in email validation. I don't know whats the wrong within my code and i am not able to validate user mail id. Below is my code and the error where i am getting is at @ symbol in my code. Advance thanks guys.

Validation script:

```
    var emailText = document.getElementById('emailid').value;
    alert(emailText);
   var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*)*\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
    if (pattern.test(emailText)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('Bad email address: ' + emailText);
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. Since, i am working in scala, i have to add two @@ for email validation instead of one

```
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)*@@[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*)*\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the `@` character with `\`.

But your code works perfectly fine even without it:

```js
function testmail(emailText) {
  alert(emailText);
  var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*)*\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
  if (pattern.test(emailText)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Bad email address: ' + emailText);
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(testmail("sven.petroll@gmailcom")? "good" : "bad"); //bad
console.log(testmail("sven.petroll@gmail.com")? "good" : "bad"); //good
```